# Loading a UIWebView from a UITableView in same ViewController Not Working

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uiwebview, horizontal-scrolling

I'm working on a iPad app and I'm having a problem with the webview loading. I have a `ViewController` with Horizontal scrolling tableview at the top. In this tableview a another tableview is added as a subview and rotated 90 degrees and then a custom cell is loaded in to this. This gives me the horizontal scrolling effect. The UIWebview is then directly below the tableview. The tableview is populated by news articles and i want to load the full webpage when the article is selected. Everything works fine apart from the `UIWebView` doesn't load. Ive tried everything i can think of & can't figure out why.

Its a bit complicated how everything is set out so ill try and explain everything i can. 
The main Viewcontroller which the UIWebView is in uses HorizontalTableViewController as its class. The tableview use HorizontalTableCell as its class. Heres the code I'm using to load the UIWebView:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];



NSString *loadURL;
loadURL=[[[NSString alloc] initWithString:urlString]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:loadURL];

[self.horizontalTableViewController.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];







 NSLog(@"Load URL = %@",loadURL);

}
```

From the log i can see the url is correct but the UIWebView remains blank & doesn't load.
I have set up the webview as a Outlet in the HorizontalTableViewController.

The view hierarchy is:

```
2012-06-04 10:22:08.568 Bandz[21211:fb03] *** Printing out all the subviews of     HorizontalTableViewController (UIViewController) ***
2012-06-04 10:22:08.570 Bandz[21211:fb03]    [0]: class: 'UITableView'
2012-06-04 10:22:08.570 Bandz[21211:fb03]       [0]: class: 'UIImageView'
2012-06-04 10:22:08.571 Bandz[21211:fb03]       [1]: class: 'UIImageView'
2012-06-04 10:22:08.571 Bandz[21211:fb03]    [1]: class: 'UINavigationBar'
2012-06-04 10:22:08.572 Bandz[21211:fb03]       [0]: class: 'UINavigationBarBackground'
2012-06-04 10:22:08.572 Bandz[21211:fb03]       [1]: class: 'UINavigationItemView'
2012-06-04 10:22:08.572 Bandz[21211:fb03]       [2]: class: 'UINavigationButton'
2012-06-04 10:22:08.573 Bandz[21211:fb03]          [0]: class: 'UIButtonLabel'
2012-06-04 10:22:08.573 Bandz[21211:fb03]    [2]: class: 'UIWebView'
2012-06-04 10:22:08.574 Bandz[21211:fb03]       [0]: class: '_UIWebViewScrollView'
2012-06-04 10:22:08.575 Bandz[21211:fb03]          [0]: class: 'UIImageView'
2012-06-04 10:22:08.575 Bandz[21211:fb03]          [1]: class: 'UIImageView'
2012-06-04 10:22:08.576 Bandz[21211:fb03]          [2]: class: 'UIImageView'
2012-06-04 10:22:08.576 Bandz[21211:fb03]          [3]: class: 'UIImageView'
2012-06-04 10:22:08.577 Bandz[21211:fb03]          [4]: class: 'UIImageView'
2012-06-04 10:22:08.595 Bandz[21211:fb03]          [5]: class: 'UIImageView'
2012-06-04 10:22:08.595 Bandz[21211:fb03]          [6]: class: 'UIImageView'
2012-06-04 10:22:08.596 Bandz[21211:fb03]          [7]: class: 'UIImageView'
2012-06-04 10:22:08.596 Bandz[21211:fb03]          [8]: class: 'UIImageView'
2012-06-04 10:22:08.597 Bandz[21211:fb03]          [9]: class: 'UIImageView'
2012-06-04 10:22:08.597 Bandz[21211:fb03]          [10]: class: 'UIWebBrowserView'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the situation correctly, you shouldn't be using a whole different view controller. A view controller within a view controller is never a good idea, if it's even possible. Create a UITableView (or subclass), without the controller. Then create a property for the UITableView and set its properties in your didSelectRowAtIndex.

Comment: Sorry i didn't explain it very well, i have one ViewController with a UITableView and a UIWebView. When a article is selected i want it to load in the UIWebView. To make things more complicated the article is in a subview of a tableview loaded in the main tablevew to achieve the horizontal scrolling.

Comment: If you have only one view controller, you shouldn't be instantiating HorizontalViewController in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Give us the exact view hierarchy for the UIWebView, and what UITableViews you're using. Be sure to not confuse a UITableView with a UITableViewController.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't initially instantiate HorizontalViewController in didSelectRowAtIndexPath i was just trying different things I've changed it back now to original code above. As for view hierarchy I've also included it above. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Anymore Ideas? Still Stumped!

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you don't initialize your webview at any point. Try doing this in viewDidLoad, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you're doing this in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, since that method is only called when the user taps on a row in the table. Code for putting something into a cell should be called in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

With your design, however, you're going to run into a problem. You have two table views in your view controller, and both have their delegates set to `self`, then in any of the `tableView:...` methods you implement, you'll need to check the `tableView` parameter so you know which table view is making the call.

Finally, your `HorizontalTableViewController` class contains your `UIWebView` in some way, but  it does not look like your description in the question. Post the code for that bit, too - it may be that you're not instantiating the web view.

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear, i don't want to put anything in the cell, articles are loaded perfectly fine from a rss feed into the table, i just want to load the full article in the UIWebView when you select a article. The HorizontalTableCell class is where the method is called, cos I'm getting the log of the url fine. As for the UIWebview I've defined it as a outlet in the HorizontalTableViewController.